# Orthogonal matrix preserves volume

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

An $n\times n$ matrix is said to be *orthogonal* if $AA^T = A^TA = I_n$; that is, if $A^T = A^{-1}$
    (It turns out that in two or three dimensions, the orthogonal matrices describe rotations and reflections).
    Suppose that $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear transformation with standard matrix $A$, and $A$ is orthogonal.
    Show that $T$ preserves volume: if $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a solid with volume $V$, then $T(S)$ also has volume $V$.

So this is my question. I did not have any clue at this moment. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You should show your attempts

Comment: If you are talking about general solids, not just parallelepiped, then you may need an analysis tag here. You may start with interpreting the determinant as a signed volume and using $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: Any isometry preserves volumes. You may show this either by invoking a decomposition in polytopes or by computing a Jacobian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea. Show that if you have any cube, $T$ preserves its volume. Then you can think of any volume as a sum of little cubes, like 3D Riemann integral sums such things to get volumes...